# Cannot clear one of the page items via dynamic action

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a couple of text fields that are filled from the database when the value of a select list changed.

I added another action to the list change dynamic action to execute PL/SQL code:

```
IF :P2_SELECT_LIST1 LIKE '%ABC%' AND :P2_NAME = 'WWW' THEN
   :P2_NAME = NULL;
END IF;
```

Nothing happend on the page when I change the value of the select list, but the session value of P2_NAME gets cleared.

I also tried:

```
IF :P2_SELECT_LIST1 LIKE '%ABC%' AND :P2_NAME = 'WWW' THEN
    :P2_NAME = '';
END IF;
```

But gotten the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this dynamic action there are two fields next to your pl/sql code:

- Items to submit: list the items here that you use in your pl/sql to get the values from session (if necessary, the values are usually already in session).
- Items to return: list the items here that you need to refresh the value on the HTML page after some change in your pl/sql

I think this solves the problem.